# Consulta viene ordenada por defecto? phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

He visto que al hacer una consulta en phpmyadmin te la ordena por defecto, las consultas vienen ordenadas por defecto de algun modo, o hay que realizar siempre un ORDER BY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Los motores de bases de datos no ordenan las respuestas a las consultas de ninguna manera, si no que devuelven los registros a medida que los van procesando (y esto tambien depende del motor).

Ninguna base de datos, asegura que lo que se traiga va a estar ordenado, a menos que agregues una clausula `order by` a tu select.

Es mas, ninguna base de datos asegura que ante la misma consulta, el orden en que va a traer los registros sea el mismo (aunque generalmente lo es, no se asegura en ningun lado).

Sy phpmyadmin ordena alguna salida, puede ser un comportamiento standard de la herramienta de visualizacion (phpmyadmin **no es** un motor de base de datos).

Asi que si queres asegurar una salida que sea siempre igual, tenes que usar `order by`